# Fancybox 2.1.5 not scrolling with page (vertical centering)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox-2

I'm updating my site and I'm having a problem where on my illustration page (a really tall page with about 600 images), the fancybox will not center vertically if you scroll down. So if you go down the page and click an image, the screen just dims a bit as the box appears off-screen. This behavior only seems to affect chrome (out of the 3 I tested chrome, firefox and ie), and I've seen questions similar to this with answers I couldn't apply to the code I have in place. [Here's the problem page](http://butterflysmasher.com/5102/illustration.html)

I have modified the code with my own theme, and wonder if I may have just fudged something.  [here's the script on the server for reference](http://butterflysmasher.com/5102/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js)

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {$(".fancybox").fancybox({'margin':'20'});});
```

Comment: Couldn't find the place in the code to replace with this, so I tried pasting it at the beginning/end of the .js, which doesn't seem to have had any effect.